# Any way to selectively apply margins to PDF generated with puppeteer?

Tags: css, node.js, pdf, puppeteer

I am writing a node program that will dynamically generate a PDF from a targeted webpage and stream it back to the browser. I am using puppeteer for the PDF generation, and the webpage I am designing is a product catalog.

For this catalog, I want the first page to be a full width graphic with no margin, but for the rest of the PDF (which is a large table) I want to apply margins to the document.

My code looks like this:

```
let viewportOptions = {
  width: 1680,
  height: 948,
  isLandscape: eval(req.params.orientation === "landscape")
};

let pdfOptions = {
  path: "",
  format: "letter",
  scale: 1,
  landscape: eval(req.params.orientation === "landscape"),
  printBackground: true,
  deviceScaleFactor: 2
  margin: { top: "1cm", bottom: "1cm", left: "1cm", right: "1cm" }
};

(async() => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.setViewport(viewportOptions);
  await page.goto(`${fileData}`, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
  page.emulateMedia(null);
  const PDFresult = await page.pdf(pdfOptions);
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.send(PDFresult);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

I can apply margins to the whole document no problem, but is there a good programmatic way to apply margins only to the pages following the first? I don't see a way to do this within the puppeteer API but there must be another way to accomplish this.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

the page.pdf(option) === ctrl+p  so if you  want to set height and width  you should set page height and width to get your final result ;
 try this code :

```
 await page1.setViewport({
    width: 1920, height: 1080, fitWindow: false, deviceScaleFactor: 1, mobile: false, waitLoad: true,
    waitNetworkIdle: true
});
await common.launch(page1);
```